# Show a YAML metadata value in reveal.js slide (w. pandoc)

Tags: yaml, pandoc, reveal.js

I would like to know if it's possible to print the value of a YAML metadata item in a reveal.js slide produced through pandoc.

I know these are mostly planned to use in templates and I have been able to do so without problems, but I would like to show the value of one of those in the **content** of a slide. Is this somehow possible?

I've looked at the template syntax (`$variable-name$`) but of course that does not work in the content.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to write a short [Lua filter](https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html) for this:

```lua
function Pandoc (doc)
  local meta = doc.meta
  return doc:walk {
    RawInline = function (raw)
      if raw.format == 'metavar' then
        return pandoc.utils.type(meta[raw.text]) == 'Blocks' and
          pandoc.utils.blocks_to_inlines(meta[raw.text]) or
          meta[raw.text]
      end
    end
  }
end
```

Usage: save the above to a file `metavar.lua` and use it in your conversion with `--lua-filter=metavar.lua`. Then include variables like this:

```markdown
The value of `title` is `title`{=metavar}.
```

---

An alternative solution would be to use [Quarto](https://quarto.org), which builds on pandoc and uses it under the hood. Quarto comes with short-codes that [allow to access meta values](https://quarto.org/docs/authoring/variables.html#meta):

```markdown
The value of `title` is {{< meta title >}}.
```

Comment: This worked great, thanks!

Quarto has been on my radar for a while, but I have the Markdown to reveal.js through pandoc (in Sublime) working well for my needs so I'm lazy to test it just now...